# Populating heading fields via ajax callback based on field name

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to populate all the h6 fields after an ajax call. Everything works except for the h6.each function which populates h6 field. Where did the script go wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="box-profile"">
  <h6 class="text-muted" name="first_name">
  <h6 class="text-muted" name="title"></h6>
  <h6 class="text-muted" name="phone"></h6>
  <h6 class="text-muted" name="fax"></h6>
  <h6 class="text-muted" name="email"></h6>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'sql/ajax-load.php',
   data:{account_list:account_list},
   success: function(response){
     var data = JSON.parse(response);
     var titles = $('h6').each(function(){
       var json = data[this.name];
       if(json !== ""){
         this.text = json;
       }else{
         this.text = '';
       }
     console.log(json + err);
   };
  });
```

PHP

```
  $account_list = $_POST['account_list'];  
  $sql = $DB_CON_A->prepare("SELECT * FROM staffs WHERE account=:account_list");
  $sql->bindValue(':account_list', $account_list, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sql->execute();
  $staff = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  die(json_encode($staff));
```

Comment: what is `data`? You are calling the server response `response` not `data`. Look at error in browser console

Comment: Sorry...I had no idea I left out "var data = JSON.parse(response);" when I posted this issue but the original code had that in but it didn't work. I just edited my post.

Comment: Also, it worked for input fields but not heading fields which make my head scratched.

Comment: `name` is not a property of content tags like it is for form controls. Try `data[$(this).attr('name')]`

Comment: Tried it too, but no lucks though.

Comment: What does data look like? Create a demo that reproduces problem

Comment: Note `this.text` is invalid...try `$(this).text(json)`

Comment: Man...it works like miracle! Thank you!